# Solving $y'-y=2\cos 5t$ using the Laplace Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, laplace-transform

> Find the solution to the differential equation, using the Laplace Transform.
>
> $y'-y=2\cos 5t$, with initial condition $y(0)=0$.

My attempt:
First I take the Laplace Transform of each term.

$\mathscr{L}\{y'\}-\mathscr{L}\{y\}=2\mathscr{L}\{\cos 5t\}\\
sY(s)-y(0)-Y(s)=2\cdot \dfrac{s^2}{s^2+25}\\
Y(s)(s-1)=\dfrac{2s^2}{s^2+25}\\
Y(s)=\dfrac{2s^2}{s^2+25}\cdot \dfrac{1}{s-1}=\dfrac{2s^2}{(s^2+25)(s-1)}$

Applying partial fraction decomposition:

$\dfrac{2s^2}{(s^2+25)(s-1)}=\dfrac{A}{s-1}+\dfrac{Bs+C}{s^2+25}\\
\implies \dfrac{2s^2}{(s^2+25)(s-1)}=\dfrac{(s^2+25)A+(s-1)(Bs+C)}{(s-1)(s^2+25)}\\
\implies 2s^2=(s^2+25)A+(s-1)(Bs+C)$

Letting $s=1, \\2=26A\implies A=\dfrac{1}{13}\\$

Expanding the partial fraction,

$2s^2=As^2+25A+Bs^2+Cs-Bs-C\\
\implies (2)s^2=(A+B)s^2+(C-B)s+(25A-C)\\
\text{Equating coefficients get me:}\\
A+B=2\quad \text{(1)}\\
C-B=0\quad \text{(2)}\\
25A-C=0\quad \text{(3)}$

Substituting $A=\dfrac{1}{13}$ into $\text{(1)}:\\
\dfrac{1}{13} + B=2\\
\implies B=2-\dfrac{1}{13}
\\B=\dfrac{26}{13}-\dfrac{1}{13}
\\B=\dfrac{25}{13}$

Substituting $B=\dfrac{25}{13}$ into $\text{(2)}:\\
C-\dfrac{25}{13}=0\\
C=\dfrac{25}{13}$

To make sure I didn't mess up any of the arithmetic, I substitute these values for $A,B,C$ into $\dfrac{A}{(s-1)}+\dfrac{Bs+C}{(s^2+25)}.$ After substituting the values in, I should get $2s^2$.

Subbing the values in:

$\dfrac{\frac{1}{13}}{s-1}+\dfrac{\frac{25}{13}s+\frac{25}{13}}{s^2+25}\\
=\frac{1}{13}s^2+\frac{25}{13}+\left (\frac{25}{13}s+\frac{25}{13}\right)(s-1)\\=
\frac{1}{13}s^2+\frac{25}{13}+\frac{25}{13}s^2-\frac{25}{13}s+\frac{25}{13}s-\frac{25}{13}\\
=\frac{1}{13}s^2+\frac{25}{13}s^2=\frac{26}{13}s^2=2s^2$.

So the partial fraction decomposition is good.

---

I now proceed to take the Inverse Laplace Transform:

$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{Y(s)\}=\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\dfrac{\frac{1}{13}}{s-1}\right\}+\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\dfrac{\frac{25}{13}s}{s^2+25}\right\}+\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\dfrac{\frac{25}{13}}{s^2+25}\right\}\\
\implies y(t)=\frac{1}{13}\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\dfrac{1}{s-1}\right\}+\frac{25}{13}\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\dfrac{s}{s^2+25}\right\}+\frac{25}{13}\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{\dfrac{1}{s^2+25}\right\}\\
\implies y(t)=\frac{1}{13}e^t+\frac{25}{13}\cos 5t+\frac{25}{13}\cdot \frac{1}{5}\sin 5t\\
\implies y(t)=\frac{1}{13}e^t+\frac{25}{13}\cos 5t+\frac{5}{13}\sin 5t$

...and so I thought that's the solution, but when I substitute $y(t)$ into the original differential equation, I'm not getting $2\cos 5t$, so I suppose I messed up somewhere. If someone can tell me where I went wrong (if I went wrong), it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can easily check your answer for $y(t)$ by just seeing whether the original differential equation holds for it.

Comment: I tried substituting $y(t)$ into the original differential equation, but it doesn't give me $2\cos 5t$. I am getting $-\frac{120}{13}\sin 5t+\frac{50}{13}\cos 5t$.

Comment: The homogeneous solution is $e^t$. Then we have $y' - y = e^{5it} + e^{-5it}$. So guess a solution of $k\cdot e^{it}+c\cdot e^{5it}+d\cdot e^{-5it}$ and we get $5c - c = 4c = 1$ and $-5d -d = -6d = 1$. So, $c = 1/4$ and $d = -1/6$. Finally, solving IBP we get $k = -1/12$. So, $y(t) = -1/12\cdot e^t + 1/4\cdot e^{5it} - 1/6\cdot e^{5it}$.

Comment: My answer above is a different method, but it shows you what is, in my opinion, a better method and allows you to check your answer. On this note, why use Laplace transforms for such a simple ODE? The answer is purely algebraic in terms of $e^t, e^{5it}, e^{-5it}$. Note that the last term should be $-1/6 \cdot e^{-5it}$ and not $-1/6 \cdot e^{5it}$.

Comment: Note by the way that you can do the partial fractions part of this problem (which is most of it!) a lot easier by using the [cover-up method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method). The time spent learning this method will have paid for itself by the time you've done two Laplace transform problems.

Comment: Your mistake is at the very beginning. The Laplace transform of the cosine term is incorrect. There is no $s^2$ term in the numerator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mistake in the Laplace transform of the cosine:

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \cos (\omega t)e^{-st}\,dt &= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty e^{(i\omega-s)t} + e^{-(i\omega+s)t}\,dt\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{e^{(i\omega-s)t}}{i\omega-s} - \frac{e^{-(i\omega+s)t}}{i\omega+s}\right]_0^\infty\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{i\omega+s} - \frac{1}{i\omega-s}\right]\\
&= \frac{(i\omega-s)-(i\omega+s)}{2(i\omega+s)(i\omega-s)}\\
&= \frac{-2s}{2(-\omega^2-s^2)}\\
&= \frac{s}{\omega^2+s^2},
\end{align}$$

so $2\mathscr{L}\{\cos 5t\} = \dfrac{2s}{s^2+25}$, not $\dfrac{2s^2}{s^2+25}$, you have a factor $s$ too much. I expect that after correcting that, it will work out.

Comment: Ah. Of course I'd make a mistake in the very first step. Thanks.